# Regex to get return the first two ints

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a string like: #/projects/58/tasks/140

I want to be able to extract 58 & 140.

I have the following:

```
parseInt(hash.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

This gets 58, but I can't get 140 with:

```
parseInt(hash.match(/\d+/)[1])
```

y? thanks

Comment: There are some libraries that can handle hash routing. For example, [SammyJS](http://sammyjs.org/) and [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Controller-routes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "g" modifier

```
 hash.match(/\d+/g)
```